# As + indefinite article

Tags: grammar, indefinite-article

Should the word **as**, when referring to a role / job, be followed by an indefinite article or not?

I would like to apply for a summer job **as a** shop assistant.

I would like to apply for a summer job **as** shop assistant.

Comment: you definitely need "a" there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying for one job among several/many workers doing the same thing, the indefinite article is needed.

> I've applied for a job as a shop assistant.
>
> He used to work as a postman in London.

However, if the job is a unique one we either use the definite article or omit it altogether.

> He used to be the Vicar of Wakefield.
>
> They have all served as President of the United States.